# Save date array to db

Tags: drupal, date, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

So, I have this element in my form:

```
<?php
$form['order']['date'] = array(
        '#type'          => 'date',
        '#title'         => 'Order date',
      );
```

In the form submit function I have got such array:

```
[values] => Array
    (
        [date] => Array
            (
                [year] => 2010
                [month] => 11
                [day] => 27
            )
    )
```

I am looking for a simple way to save this array in database and then I want to be able to extract this date from the database for that would be substituted back into the edit form.

Are there drupal api functions for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found a simple way to do it, but it does not use Drupal api.

```
$date = implode($form_state['values']['date']); // $date = 20101127;
```

Comment: You do realize that the result is *NOT* a Unix timestamp?!?

Comment: Why do you think that the result should be a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Because dates are best stored as Unix timestamps. Take for example the two dates: *9/11/2001* and *11/11/2000*. Without doubt the first comes AFTER the second but once you implode the date arrays the way you are, the latter would win a simple date comparison: `2001911 < 20001111`. On top of that, you are relying on an implicit assumption that the order of a date element array's keys is `year`, `month`, `day` (which could change any time without you noticing it). There's even more but I think you get the point.

Comment: I agree that timestamp is better way. But the question is about date serialization. There is nothing about data processing and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Date module will give you API calls to do this.

In my case my requirements were fairly simple, and I didn't want to create an extra module dependency so I used the following to form a PHP DateTime object:

```
$date_arr = $form_state['values']['date'];
if ($date_arr['year'] && $date_arr['month'] && $date_arr['day']) {
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date->setDate($date_arr['year'], $date_arr['month'], $date_arr['day']);
} else {
  $date = NULL;
}
```

To store in a database (as a UNIX timestamp, as is the Drupal convention), I used $date->getTimestamp().

I didn't need put date back into a form, but if I did, I'd try something like:

```
$query = db_query("select mydate from table");
while ($fields = db_fetch_array($query)) {
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date->setTimestamp($fields[0]);
  $form['order']['date'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'date',
    '#title'         => 'Order date',
    '#default_value' => array(
      year  => $date->format('Y'),
      month => $date->format('m'),
      day   => $date->format('d'),
    ),
  );
}
```

I haven't tested this, so you'll need to experiment.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could just [serialize](http://us.php.net/serialize) it and store it as a serialized array in the database. Then when you want to display it, you call [unserialize](http://us.php.net/unserialize) on the database column and you have the original array back.

```
//in your submit function
$date = serialize($values['date']);
$sql = "UPDATE foobar SET date = '%s' WHERE id = '%d'";
db_query($sql, $date, $some_id);

//in your form function
$date_array = db_result(db_query("SELECT date FROM foo WHERE id = '%d'", $some_id));
$form['date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => 'Order date',
  '#default_value' => $date_array,  
);
```

Comment: That would be a very bad idea, if you need to do anything with the date, like get the 10 most recent, all from november etc. This can be done with SQL, but not if you serialize the date, instead of saving it as a date.

Comment: Yes, ORDER BY `date` is required.

Comment: Yes, bad idea. Also: You should always program to an interface. Having this kind of thing in your form API doesn't promote reuse and readability. Use some helper functions that handle formatting and delegate to them in your forms.

Comment: Ah. If you need to order by date, then this is indeed a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it depends on how you need to store the date. A time stamp or a date or a datetime or some custom format?

You wont find any API to make the date into a date string, but if you use the date module to create a date field, the date module will convert the data to a date string with the usual ISO format that databases use.

Comment: I have INT(10) format in database field and I don't want to use external modules. If I shall not find the appropriate drupal function, then I'll use  native php functions.

Answer (score 0):

I can point you in the right direction.

There is functionality in the API to do the work for you. Dates are a bit fiddly and will require some patience.

Take a look at the date element in the form reference API. There's probably a hook that you can use to do your formatting.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6

You should be familiar with hook_elements(). There's some attributes that will interest you such as '#process' where you can add callbacks to the date element that get executed on form submit. This hook is very under rated.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_elements/6

The profile module has an example (hard to find it though):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/function/profile_form_profile/6

Dates are mostly stored in the database as timestamps. These can be easily converted with format_date:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/6

:)

Comment: I have not found any drupal way to convert array of date values in timestamp format. 
I have already explored the profile module, it serialzes date.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses (un)serialize for the date array in the db, i assume it's a profile field. If you use serialize to write it to the db, Drupal can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method of date storage in Drupal is in UNIX time format. I would recommend converting the date in your form to UNIX time using the [mktime function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or something similar.

Here's a simple example:

```
$my_date = mktime(23, 59, 59, $order->values['date']['month'], $order->values['date']['day'], $order->values['date']['year']);
```

Then use the $my_date variable in your DB insert/update.